# How to modify Data Frame so as to take values between some other character in column in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, if-statement

I have DataFrame in Python Pandas like below:

```
COL_1 | COL_2               | COL_3
------|---------------------|---------
111   | CV_COUNT_ABC_XM_BF  | CV_SUM_ABC_XM_BF
222   | CV_COUNT_DEF_XM_BF  | CV_SUM_CC_XM_BF
333   | CV_COUNT_CC_XM_BF   | LACK
444   | LACK                | CV_SUM_DEF_XM_BF
...   | ...                 |  ...
```

And I need to modify above DataFrame to have in COL_2 and COL_3 values like:

- if there is "LACK" in COL_2 or COL_3 stay it
- if there is something other than "LACK" take value:

  ```
  between "CV_COUNNT_" and "_XM_BF" 

  or 

  between "CV_SUM_" and "_XM_BF"
  ```

So, as a result I need something like below:

```
COL_1 | COL_2             | COL_3
------|-------------------|---------
111   | ABC               | ABC
222   | DEF               | CC
333   | CC                | LACK
444   | LACK              | DEF
...   | ...               | ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `np.where` along with `str.extract` here:

```py
df["COL_2"] = np.where(df["COL_2"] == 'LACK', df["COL_2"],
                       df["COL_2"].str.extract(r'CV_COUNT_(\w+?)_XM_BF'))
df["COL_3"] = np.where(df["COL_3"] == 'LACK', df["COL_3"],
                   df["COL_3"].str.extract(r'CV_SUM_(\w+?)_XM_BF'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replace`:

```
df = df.replace({'COL_2': {'CV_COUNT_(\w+)_XM_BF': r'\1'},
                 'COL_3': {'CV_SUM_(\w+)_XM_BF': r'\1'}}, regex=True)
print(df)

# Output
   COL_1 COL_2 COL_3
0    111   ABC   ABC
1    222   DEF    CC
2    333    CC  LACK
3    444  LACK   DEF
```

A shortest version: `df.replace({'CV_(?:COUNT|SUM)_(\w+)_XM_BF': r'\1'}, regex=True)`

Comment: Very minor detail, but you may want to capture `(\w+?)`, since `\w+` will also match underscore.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen. Thanks for your comment. I asked myself this question too but I can't figure out if it matters since the right part is static? Do you have a use case where it doesn't work here?

Comment: Yes: `CV_COUNT_ABC_XM_XM_BF` your regex would capture `ABC_XM` ... unlikely though